# simple function in dired to create a dir with current date?

Tags: dired, functions

so im trying to create a simple script to create a directory in dired with a pre defined string (the current date). i have another script that inputs the current date in a format i want

```
(defun z-insert-date (&optional addTimeStamp-p)

"Insert current date and or time. In this format yyyy-mm-dd.
 When called with `universal-argument', insert date and time, e.g.    2012-05-28T07:06:23-07:00
Replaces text selection.See also `current-date-time-string'."
(interactive "P")
(when (region-active-p) (delete-region (region-beginning) (region- end)   ) )
(cond
((equal addTimeStamp-p nil ) (insert (format-time-string "%d%m%Y")))
(t (insert (current-date-time-string))) ) )
```

now im struggling how to bring it all togheter. i have this

```
(defun z/dired-insert-date-folder ()
 ""
 (interactive)
 (dired-create-directory (z-insert-date))
 )
```

but this dosent work and dosent seem the proper way to do it :)

can anyone point me in the right direction? maybe the `z-insert-date function` isnt really needed (i want my date to have the format of `%d%m%Y`though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be over thinking this.

```
(defun z/dired-insert-date-folder ()
  "Create new directory with current date"
  (interactive)
  (dired-create-directory (format-time-string "%d%m%Y")))
```

Your reasons are your own of course, but a format of `%Y%m%d` does tend to sort better.

Comment: That's great. Can we create yymmdd.org in a similar way?

Comment: Use `(format-time-string "%Y%m%d.org)`  for yyyymmdd.org, or `"%y%m%d.org"` if you actually want yymmdd.org

Answer (score 0):

Function `dired-create-directory` expects a string as an argument. Your function `z-insert-date` that you use as the argument has some minor issues in addition to not returning anything. It only inserts the string in the current buffer.